# How do I adjust my jig so that it can accept larger diameter wire?

Tags: selection-tools, properties, path, units

I am building [Malt Whiskey's LED cube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ciaFar8nfHc&t=729s) and need to adjust his jigs he created to solder the LEDs. He is using .65mm wire and I am using .8mm. The large holes in the model below are for the LEDs and there are 8 vertical channels for the wire. There are also a couple of rows to solder the wire horizontally. How do I select all of the channels and then make them bigger to accept larger diameter wire?

My blend file: [image]

Thanks!

Comment: Hello could you please show a screenshot of the object and highlight the parts that you want to scale?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to transparency with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, select the 8 series of slots, in the *Transform Pivot Point* panel choose the *Individual Origins* option, scale 1.231 on X (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>1.231)</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: I'm looking to increase the diameter of the channels for the wire. The LEDs seem to be fine.

Comment: The wire channels run parallel to the LEDs and run the full length of the jig. There are eight channels - two for each LED.

Comment: I've edited, does it answer?